# In PHP code on clicking a link javascript function call

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

```
<?PHP 
$result = mysql_query($query);
$finalval=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$finalval=$finalval."<a onClick='showContent("please display")' 
href='#' >".  $row['Title']   ."</a> <br>" ;
}
echo  $finalval;
 ?>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"  >

function showContent(value)
{
alert value;

}
</script>
```

Guys please help me out and please please tell me in a php code on clicking link how to call javascript/ajax function..Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one ,opening double quotes within double quotes you need to escape them `\`

```
$finalval=$finalval."<a onClick='showContent(\"please display\")' 
href='#' >".  $row['Title']   ."</a> <br>" ;
}
```

Comment: sorry to say but it dint work :/ though there is no error now but still the text is not displayed ..please help me

Comment: @InnocentHeart any error you got ? have you tried `alert(value)` in your js function

Answer (score 2):

try `alert(value)` instead of `alert value`

Comment: heyya its working fine..:) thanks a ton..but what if i want to pass row id like $finalval=$finalval. "<a href='#'  onClick='showContent(. $row['ID'] .)'>". $row['Title'] . "</a> <br>" ;

Comment: Please remember to put them in quotes so that its taken as a string for eg : `'showContent(". $row['ID'] .")'`

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?PHP
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $finalval = 0;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
             $finalval = $finalval."<a class='show-content' data-value='please display' href='#' >".  $row['Title']   ."</a> <br>" ;
        }
        echo $finalval;
    ?>
```

With javascript querySelectorAll get all a links with class selector then handle them

```
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"  >
        var element = document.querySelectorAll(".show-content");
        for (var link in element) {
           element[link].onclick = function() {
                 showContent(this.getAttribute('data-value'));
           };
        }
       function showContent(value){
           alert(value);
       }
     </script>
```

with jQuery it is pretty stright forward,

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"  >
      $(document).ready(function(){
         $("a.content").on('click', function(){
              alert($(this).data('value')); 
              // or make a specific function call
         }); 
      });
  </script>
```

Hope this will help you, and do not forget to escape the special charactors as mentioned by [M Khalid Junaid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/853360/m-khalid-junaid)

Comment: thank you so much for your response but i usually get confused with jquery so i avoid using it..and yep my problem is solved will you pls try to answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582216/displaying-databases-row-value-in-javascript-function-in-php/20582294?noredirect=1#20582294 thank you :)

Comment: You can change echo <a class="show-content" data-value="'.$row['ID'].'" href="#">'.$row['Title'] .'</a>';
then manipulate with showContent(id) function from javascript.